# How to prevent duplicate initialState from client response in next-redux-wrapper?

Tags: next.js, next-redux-wrapper

I am using next redux wrapper in App.getInitialProps but in client response I get duplicated initialState are: initialState outside pageProps and inside pageProps, this happens everytime when navigate to another page. How can I fix it?

You can see the image below:
[image]

My code below:

```
function App({ Component, pageProps }) {

    return (
        <Layout>
           <Component {...pageProps} />
        </Layout>
    );
}

App.getInitialProps = wrapper.getInitialPageProps((store) => async (context) => {
    if (context.req) {
        const dataAuth = await fetchAuth(context);
        // dispatch action auth to update data initialState 
        // this only running on the server-side
        if (dataAuth) store.dispatch(authSlice.actions.setAuth(dataAuth));
        else store.dispatch(authSlice.actions.resetAuth());
    }
});
```